# Sql UPATE with multiple conditions in WHERE clause

Tags: sql-update

```
UPDATE Table1
    SET [Marks] = 
      (
       SELECT
       CASE STATEMENTS
       FROM Table2 T2
   WHERE Table1.ID = T2.ID)              
         )
```

The above UPDATE statements works fine, but if the ID doesn't match then it insert NULL value for 'Marks'.
But i wanted to keep the original value for Marks in Table1 if the Table1 and Table2 ID doesn't match.
How do i implement that in my code please.

i also tried using WHERE EXISTS BUT STILL no luck. I wonder whats the exact use of it.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE Table1
SET [Marks] = 
      (
       SELECT
          CASE STATEMENTS
       FROM Table2 T2
       WHERE Table1.ID = T2.ID)              
      )
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM table2)
```

Comment: @ Yasser El-Alaily : Wow! It works Perfect. You are a Star. Many thanks.

Comment: Thank you @Marc_s. Thats exactly what i did.